# Magento module controller is loaded but doesn't work

Tags: magento, module

I'm trying to create my first module for magento. I can't figure out why magento gives me a 404 when I go to the action's url.

In System -> Configuration -> Advanced the module is enabled.
PS the cache is disabled.

URL: http://www.magento.loc/newsletter/groups/index

Here my files:

/app/code/local/Maintux/NeswletterExtensions/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Maintux_NewsletterExtensions>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Maintux_NewsletterExtensions>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <newsletterextensions>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Maintux_NewsletterExtensions</module>
                    <frontName>newsletter</frontName>
                </args>
            </newsletterextensions>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

/app/code/local/Maintux/NeswletterExtensions/controllers/GroupsController.php

```
<?php
class Maintux_NewsletterExtensions_GroupsController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
       echo 'Hello Index!';
    }
}
```

/app/etc/modules/Maintux_NewsletterExtensions.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Mainutx_NewsletterExtensions>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <depends>
        <Mage_Newsletter/>
      </depends>
    </Mainutx_NewsletterExtensions>
  </modules>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you have a typo in your folder name.
Please change `NeswletterExtensions` to `NewsletterExtensions`.

And also a typo in your `app/etc/modules/Maintux_NewsletterExtensions.xml`.
Please change `Mainutx_NewsletterExtensions` to `Maintux_NewsletterExtensions`.

Comment: Oh, thanks, but it doesn't work anyway. Any hints to debug this issue?

Comment: Updatet my answer: found another typo.

Comment: Great! Thanks so much! Sorry but magento is so verbose and find typos is a little bit tricky